# Finding the boundaries of the double integral where $D$ is bounded by $y = x - 20$ and $x = y^2$

Tags: integration

I'm trying to find the double integral of $f(x,y) = y$. I'm so confused as to where to find the boundaries. I can find the $y$ boundaries by setting $y$ equal to $x - 20$ and $\sqrt{x}$, but how can I find the $x$ boundaries?

Comment: Did you graph the solutions to both equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The points of intersection of the curves satisfy the equations of both the curves.

Continuing from your start,
$$x-20=\sqrt{x}$$
$$x^2-40x+400=x$$
$$x^2-41x+400=0$$
$$x=\frac{41\pm\sqrt{41^2-1600}}{2}$$
$$x=\frac{41\pm9}{2}$$
$$x=25,16$$
which gives, on substitution, $$y=5,-4$$
respectively.

On plotting a graph, one can observe that for any $y$ in $-4$ to $5$, the region enclosed consists of $x$ taking values from the curve $y^2=x$ to the curve $y=x-20$, that is, ranging from $y^2$ to $y+20$.

So, the region is given by
$$D=\{(x,y):-4\le y\le5, y^2\le x \le y+20\}$$